# Чтение файла в память

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть функция, которая принимает указатель на данные и размер этих данных

```cpp
void test(void * data, int size);
```

Данные у меня лежат в файле (один файл - один пакет данных).

Вопрос: есть какой-то стандартно-библиотечный метод, чтобы одной-двумя строчками кода считать весь файл в память. Или нужно писать свой велосипед?

Comment: нет, `readall()`'а у stl'евских потоков нет... когда хотят отделаться малой кровью, то обычно читают через итераторы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring

Comment: На Unix ещё можно [отобразить файл в память](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)
.

Comment: На windows также можно отобразить, см MapViewOfFile.

Comment: Про MMF думал в первую очередь

Comment: @Fat-Zer Мне там решение через `stringstream` понравилось

Comment: A `fread` не весь файл считывает, или я не так понял?

Comment: @nick_n_a громоздко. Открыть файл, узнать его размер, выделить под данные память, прочитать файл, закрыть файл

Comment: Тут возникает такой вопрос. Ваше предложение кажется удобным, для x64 проблем не будет, а для x86 будет "лимит", там до 100Мб или меньше, если одним куском, и пожалуй до 1Gb если массивом кусков памяти. Вы хотите одним куском и всёравно есть лимит или нету? Возможно первым способом в какой-то из стандартных либ что-то интересное есть. А windows linux, кроссплатформа или любые случаи?

Comment: @nick_n_a это мне в отладочных целях. Файлы будут не более 10Kb. Достаточно поддержки Windows